# How trustworthy are query result counts?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I just ran a query in Logs Explorer for a 24 hour period and it returned 2409575 results
[image]

I then ran the exact query, changing only the start time and end time to define a time window that is a subset of the previous time window and it returned 2656840 results which is more than previously:
[image]

How can this be? My only conclusion from this is that the stated number of log results cannot be trusted. Can someone please inform me of what the expectations are for the log results tally? Can it be trusted?

Comment: Computers dont do what we want them to do. They do what we tell them to do. I'm sure there is something mixed up there! else a bug in gee

Comment: When you say that the stated number of log results cannot be trusted, I understand that this is something that is happening often to you. Please share more information about your issue. What was the query you used? Where do the logs come from? Were you looking for anything specific in the logs?

Comment: I want to know how many log records match the filter that I’m providing.

Comment: The logs come from a cloud function

Comment: Well, answering your question, all the logs that appear in your search are the logs that match your filter. Nevertheless, I won't be able to give you a reason why you're having a bigger number of logs in a smaller time range without having the proper information. Are you using timestamps in your query or the histogram timeline to determine the time segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. The counts shown in the Log Fields panel and the Histogram are reliable. Only the total query results appear to have an issue due to the the nature of the incremental and approximate counts as logs are read. The final value should have been accurate. An internal issue has been crated and the team will fixing this soon.

Disclaimer: I work in Cloud Logging.